# Eigenvalue perturbation theory for $(A^TA)(B^TB)^{-1} + (B^TB)(A^TA)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A, B$ be $n \times n$ matrices with full rank. I'm interested in getting a bound on how the smallest eigenvalue of $S = (A^TA)(B^TB)^{-1} + (B^TB)(A^TA)^{-1}$ changes when I perturb $A$ and $B$. That is, given $Sx=\lambda x$ I want a bound on $\delta \lambda$ where $\left[(\tilde{A}^T\tilde{A})(\tilde{B}^T\tilde{B})^{-1} + (\tilde{B}^T\tilde{B})(\tilde{A}^T\tilde{A})^{-1}\right](x+\delta x)=(\lambda +\delta \lambda)(x + \delta x)$ and $\tilde{A} = A + E_1$ and $\tilde{B} = B + E_2$ are perturbed versions of $A$ and $B$.

I know the trick in getting bounds for the standard non-symmetric eigenvalue problem where one subtracts $Sx$ from the left and $\lambda x$ from the right and then multiply from the left by the left eigenvector of $S$ that corresponds to $\lambda$. I'm having troubles getting anywhere in this more complicated case and in particular figure out how to deal with the perturbed inverses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just expand everything out in series, for example the first term goes like
$$ ( \bar A ^T \bar A )  = ( A^TA+E_1^T A +A^TE_1 + E_1^TE_1)$$
$$ ( \bar B ^T \bar B ) ^{-1} = ( B^TB+E_2^T B +B^TE_2 + E_2^TE_2)^{-1}=(B^TB)^{-1}( I+E_2^T B(B^TB)^{-1} +B^TE_2(B^TB)^{-1} +E_2^TE_2(B^TB)^{-1} )^{-1}$$
Then use
$$ (I + C)^{-1} \approx I - C$$
you may use more terms if you need a better bound (as long as $||E_1||,||E_2||$ are small this will be fine).

Comment: Can anyone educate me on what this approximation is? $(I + C)^{-1} \approx I - C$ is there a name?

Comment: @WeiZhong (Taylor) Series expansion.